# Easy Google Fonts Wordpress Plugin not supporting with in Free Theme Parallaxsome

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working in a website on wordpress with a free theme and I want to change font styles of site title, main menu or menus of specific divs. I tried to install Easy Google Fonts plugin but theme is not supporting it. When I activate it following error is showing

> Fatal error: Class ‘WP_Customize_Section’ not found in …wp-content\themes\parallaxsome\inc\customizer\parallaxsome-customizer-classes.php on line 386

I asked about it from theme author and he let me know to contact plugin author.

https://accesspressthemes.com/support/topic/i-want-to-change-font-family-of-site-title-and-main-menu/#post-70747

After that I asked plugin author of Easy Google Fonts and waiting for reply.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-is-not-supporting/

Please let me know the solution. If some body knows.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you read that page you will see that that plugin is not supported

Comment: Which page you are talking about?

Comment: Look at the link urls. One actually contains the words `plugin-is-not-supported` how clearer can it be

Comment: It is just my Title which I typed while typing on support forum.

Comment: You only asked that question 11 minutes ago. Wait for an answer

Comment: I am in hurry to get solution then want to finalize our website on a decided deadline.

Comment: You could perhaps try a different plugin? Like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/olympus-google-fonts/

Comment: Because I am trying to apply CSS on a text inside some specific divs or ul that is why I am giving priority to Easy Google Fonts plugin. This plugin have this option but not in others.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to hard code your changes in the theme's style.css file.

You can find the file following this path - wp-content > themes > yourtheme > style.css

Open this file using a file editor and you will be able to edit all the styling, including the font.

It will help if you use the source code as a reference so that you can find the correct classes and ids that are associated with the element.

It's pretty simple to change the font, you can use this as a reference to find the one you want - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-font-families/

EDIT: Here is an easier way that your client would perhaps understand if they have a very basic knowledge of CSS - https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/change-wordpress-appearance/change-font-globally

Alternatively, there are a ton of other plugins that will do the same thing as the Google Fonts plugin. For example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/use-any-font/

Hopefully, this will provide you with enough information to help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to give access to change font family, size and color to my client. For this I want a user-friendly option on back-end.

Comment: I've updated my answer for you, hopefully this sort you out!

Comment: Sorry but my client have not any type of knowledge about codes.

Comment: That's why I added in the last bit of my answer :p

Comment: Because I am trying to apply CSS on a text inside some specific divs or ul that is why I am giving priority to Easy Google Fonts plugin. This plugin have this option but not in others.