# Increase quantity of available font types allowed by theme in Wordpress Customize

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts

I am working on a project in wordpress with free theme and there is an option in customize to change font family, size and color but it is showing only six fonts.

```
<select data-customize-setting-link="hm_sec_title_font_family" id="hm_sec_title_typography" class="typography_face">

                        <option value="BenchNine" selected="selected">BenchNine</option>

                        <option value="Josefin Slab">Josefin Slab</option>

                        <option value="Lato">Lato</option>

                        <option value="Open Sans">Open Sans</option>

                        <option value="PT Sans">PT Sans</option>

                        <option value="Prociono">Prociono</option>

                        <option value="Raleway">Raleway</option>

                        <option value="Roboto Slab">Roboto Slab</option>

                        <option value="Source Sans Pro">Source Sans Pro</option>

                </select>
```

I want to increase these fonts quantity. I have tried many plugin to get fonts option but failed you can see our previous question.

[Easy Google Fonts Wordpress Plugin not supporting with in Free Theme Parallaxsome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386066/easy-google-fonts-wordpress-plugin-not-supporting-with-in-free-theme-parallaxsom)

I found a code in a php file customize > control-typography.php from where fonts is coming from. This is the code and I want to edit it to show more fonts.

```
    public function get_google_fonts() {
        $encoded = 'a:9:{i:0;a:8:{s:4:"kind";s:16:"webfonts#webfont";s:6:"family";s:9:"BenchNine";s:8:"category";s:10:"sans-serif";s:8:"variants";a:3:{i:0;s:3:"300";i:1;s:7:"regular";i:2;s:3:"700";}s:7:"subsets";a:2:{i:0;s:5:"latin";i:1;s:9:"latin-ext";}s:7:"version";s:2:"v6";s:12:"lastModified";s:10:"2017-10-10";s:5:"files";a:3:{i:300;s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/benchnine/v6/ah9xtUy9wLQ3qnWa2p-piS3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";s:7:"regular";s:66:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/benchnine/v6/h3OAlYqU3aOeNkuXgH2Q2w.ttf";i:700;s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/benchnine/v6/qZpi6ZVZg3L2RL_xoBLxWS3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";}}i:1;a:8:{s:4:"kind";s:16:"webfonts#webfont";s:6:"family";s:12:"Josefin Slab";s:8:"category";s:5:"serif";s:8:"variants";a:10:{i:0;s:3:"100";i:1;s:9:"100italic";i:2;s:3:"300";i:3;s:9:"300italic";i:4;s:7:"regular";i:5;s:6:"italic";i:6;s:3:"600";i:7;s:9:"600italic";i:8;s:3:"700";i:9;s:9:"700italic";}s:7:"subsets";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"latin";}s:7:"version";s:2:"v8";s:12:"lastModified";s:10:"2017-10-10";s:5:"files";a:10:{i:100;s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/etsUjZYO8lTLU85lDhZwUsSVQ0giZ-l_NELu3lgGyYw.ttf";s:9:"100italic";s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/8BjDChqLgBF3RJKfwHIYh3Xcj1rQwlNLIS625o-SrL0.ttf";i:300;s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/NbE6ykYuM2IyEwxQxOIi2KcQoVhARpoaILP7amxE_8g.ttf";s:9:"300italic";s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/af9sBoKGPbGO0r21xJulyyna0FLWfcB-J_SAYmcAXaI.ttf";s:7:"regular";s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/46aYWdgz-1oFX11flmyEfS3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";s:6:"italic";s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/etsUjZYO8lTLU85lDhZwUvMZXuCXbOrAvx5R0IT5Oyo.ttf";i:600;s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/NbE6ykYuM2IyEwxQxOIi2Gv8CylhIUtwUiYO7Z2wXbE.ttf";s:9:"600italic";s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/af9sBoKGPbGO0r21xJuly4R-5-urNOGAobhAyctHvW8.ttf";i:700;s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/NbE6ykYuM2IyEwxQxOIi2ED2ttfZwueP-QU272T9-k4.ttf";s:9:"700italic";s:89:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinslab/v8/af9sBoKGPbGO0r21xJuly_As9-1nE9qOqhChW0m4nDE.ttf";}}i:2;a:8:{s:4:"kind";s:16:"webfonts#webfont";s:6:"family";s:4:"Lato";s:8:"category";s:10:"sans-serif";s:8:"variants";a:10:{i:0;s:3:"100";i:1;s:9:"100italic";i:2;s:3:"300";i:3;s:9:"300italic";i:4;s:7:"regular";i:5;s:6:"italic";i:6;s:3:"700";i:7;s:9:"700italic";i:8;s:3:"900";i:9;s:9:"900italic";}s:7:"subsets";a:2:{i:0;s:5:"latin";i:1;s:9:"latin-ext";}s:7:"version";s:3:"v14";s:12:"lastModified";s:10:"2017-10-11";s:5:"files";a:10:{i:100;s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/Upp-ka9rLQmHYCsFgwL-eg.ttf";s:9:"100italic";s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/zLegi10uS_9-fnUDISl0KA.ttf";i:300;s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/Ja02qOppOVq9jeRjWekbHg.ttf";s:9:"300italic";s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/dVebFcn7EV7wAKwgYestUg.ttf";s:7:"regular";s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/h7rISIcQapZBpei-sXwIwg.ttf";s:6:"italic";s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/P_dJOFJylV3A870UIOtr0w.ttf";i:700;s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/iX_QxBBZLhNj5JHlTzHQzg.ttf";s:9:"700italic";s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/WFcZakHrrCKeUJxHA4T_gw.ttf";i:900;s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/8TPEV6NbYWZlNsXjbYVv7w.ttf";s:9:"900italic";s:62:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v14/draWperrI7n2xi35Cl08fA.ttf";}}i:3;a:8:{s:4:"kind";s:16:"webfonts#webfont";s:6:"family";s:9:"Open Sans";s:8:"category";s:10:"sans-serif";s:8:"variants";a:10:{i:0;s:3:"300";i:1;s:9:"300italic";i:2;s:7:"regular";i:3;s:6:"italic";i:4;s:3:"600";i:5;s:9:"600italic";i:6;s:3:"700";i:7;s:9:"700italic";i:8;s:3:"800";i:9;s:9:"800italic";}s:7:"subsets";a:7:{i:0;s:5:"latin";i:1;s:9:"latin-ext";i:2;s:8:"cyrillic";i:3;s:12:"cyrillic-ext";i:4;s:10:"vietnamese";i:5;s:5:"greek";i:6;s:9:"greek-ext";}s:7:"version";s:3:"v15";s:12:"lastModified";s:10:"2017-10-11";s:5:"files";a:10:{i:300;s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTS3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";s:9:"300italic";s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxi9-WlPSxbfiI49GsXo3q0g.ttf";s:7:"regular";s:66:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/IgZJs4-7SA1XX_edsoXWog.ttf";s:6:"italic";s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/O4NhV7_qs9r9seTo7fnsVKCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf";i:600;s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSi3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";s:9:"600italic";s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxpZ7xm-Bj30Bj2KNdXDzSZg.ttf";i:700;s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzC3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";s:9:"700italic";s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxne1Pd76Vl7zRpE7NLJQ7XU.ttf";i:800;s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/EInbV5DfGHOiMmvb1Xr-hi3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";s:9:"800italic";s:87:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/PRmiXeptR36kaC0GEAetxg89PwPrYLaRFJ-HNCU9NbA.ttf";}}i:4;a:8:{s:4:"kind";s:16:"webfonts#webfont";s:6:"family";s:7:"PT Sans";s:8:"category";s:10:"sans-serif";s:8:"variants";a:4:{i:0;s:7:"regular";i:1;s:6:"italic";i:2;s:3:"700";i:3;s:9:"700italic";}s:7:"subsets";a:4:{i:0;s:5:"latin";i:1;s:9:"latin-ext";i:2;s:8:"cyrillic";i:3;s:12:"cyrillic-ext";}s:7:"version";s:2:"v9";s:12:"lastModified";s:10:"2017-10-11";s:5:"files";a:4:{s:7:"regular";s:63:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptsans/v9/UFoEz2uiuMypUGZL1NKoeg.ttf";s:6:"italic";s:63:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptsans/v9/yls9EYWOd496wiu7qzfgNg.ttf";i:700;s:84:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptsans/v9/F51BEgHuR0tYHxF0bD4vwvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf";s:9:"700italic";s:84:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptsans/v9/lILlYDvubYemzYzN7GbLkC3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";}}i:5;a:8:{s:4:"kind";s:16:"webfonts#webfont";s:6:"family";s:8:"Prociono";s:8:"category";s:5:"serif";s:8:"variants";a:1:{i:0;s:7:"regular";}s:7:"subsets";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"latin";}s:7:"version";s:2:"v7";s:12:"lastModified";s:10:"2017-10-10";s:5:"files";a:1:{s:7:"regular";s:65:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/prociono/v7/43ZYDHWogdFeNBWTl6ksmw.ttf";}}i:6;a:8:{s:4:"kind";s:16:"webfonts#webfont";s:6:"family";s:7:"Raleway";s:8:"category";s:10:"sans-serif";s:8:"variants";a:18:{i:0;s:3:"100";i:1;s:9:"100italic";i:2;s:3:"200";i:3;s:9:"200italic";i:4;s:3:"300";i:5;s:9:"300italic";i:6;s:7:"regular";i:7;s:6:"italic";i:8;s:3:"500";i:9;s:9:"500italic";i:10;s:3:"600";i:11;s:9:"600italic";i:12;s:3:"700";i:13;s:9:"700italic";i:14;s:3:"800";i:15;s:9:"800italic";i:16;s:3:"900";i:17;s:9:"900italic";}s:7:"subsets";a:2:{i:0;s:5:"latin";i:1;s:9:"latin-ext";}s:7:"version";s:3:"v12";s:12:"lastModified";s:10:"2017-10-11";s:5:"files";a:18:{i:100;s:65:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/UDfD6oxBaBnmFJwQ7XAFNw.ttf";s:9:"100italic";s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/hUpHtml6IPNuUR-FwVi2UKCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf";i:200;s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/LAQwev4hdCtYkOYX4Oc7nPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf";s:9:"200italic";s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/N2DIbZG4399cPGfifZUEQi3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";i:300;s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/2VvSZU2kb4DZwFfRM4fLQPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf";s:9:"300italic";s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/TVSB8ogXDKMcnAAJ5CqrUi3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";s:7:"regular";s:65:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/_dCzxpXzIS3sL-gdJWAP8A.ttf";s:6:"italic";s:65:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/utU2m1gdZSfuQpArSy5Dbw.ttf";i:500;s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/348gn6PEmbLDWlHbbV15d_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf";s:9:"500italic";s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/S7vGLZZ40c85SJgiptJGVy3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";i:600;s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/M7no6oPkwKYJkedjB1wqEvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf";s:9:"600italic";s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/OY22yoG8EJ3IN_muVWm29C3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";i:700;s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/VGEV9-DrblisWOWLbK-1XPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf";s:9:"700italic";s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/lFxvRPuGFG5ktd7P0WRwKi3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";i:800;s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/mMh0JrsYMXcLO69jgJwpUvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf";s:9:"800italic";s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/us4LjTCmlYgh3W8CKujEJi3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";i:900;s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/ajQQGcDBLcyLpaUfD76UuPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.ttf";s:9:"900italic";s:86:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v12/oY2RadnkHfshu5f0FLsgVS3USBnSvpkopQaUR-2r7iU.ttf";}}i:7;a:8:{s:4:"kind";s:16:"webfonts#webfont";s:6:"family";s:11:"Roboto Slab";s:8:"category";s:5:"serif";s:8:"variants";a:4:{i:0;s:3:"100";i:1;s:3:"300";i:2;s:7:"regular";i:3;s:3:"700";}s:7:"subsets";a:7:{i:0;s:5:"latin";i:1;s:9:"latin-ext";i:2;s:8:"cyrillic";i:3;s:12:"cyrillic-ext";i:4;s:10:"vietnamese";i:5;s:5:"greek";i:6;s:9:"greek-ext";}s:7:"version";s:2:"v7";s:12:"lastModified";s:10:"2017-10-11";s:5:"files";a:4:{i:100;s:88:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoslab/v7/MEz38VLIFL-t46JUtkIEgIAWxXGWZ3yJw6KhWS7MxOk.ttf";i:300;s:88:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoslab/v7/dazS1PrQQuCxC3iOAJFEJS9-WlPSxbfiI49GsXo3q0g.ttf";s:7:"regular";s:88:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoslab/v7/3__ulTNA7unv0UtplybPiqCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf";i:700;s:88:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoslab/v7/dazS1PrQQuCxC3iOAJFEJXe1Pd76Vl7zRpE7NLJQ7XU.ttf";}}i:8;a:8:{s:4:"kind";s:16:"webfonts#webfont";s:6:"family";s:15:"Source Sans Pro";s:8:"category";s:10:"sans-serif";s:8:"variants";a:12:{i:0;s:3:"200";i:1;s:9:"200italic";i:2;s:3:"300";i:3;s:9:"300italic";i:4;s:7:"regular";i:5;s:6:"italic";i:6;s:3:"600";i:7;s:9:"600italic";i:8;s:3:"700";i:9;s:9:"700italic";i:10;s:3:"900";i:11;s:9:"900italic";}s:7:"subsets";a:7:{i:0;s:5:"latin";i:1;s:9:"latin-ext";i:2;s:8:"cyrillic";i:3;s:12:"cyrillic-ext";i:4;s:10:"vietnamese";i:5;s:5:"greek";i:6;s:9:"greek-ext";}s:7:"version";s:3:"v11";s:12:"lastModified";s:10:"2017-10-11";s:5:"files";a:12:{i:200;s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGKXvKVW_haheDNrHjziJZVk.ttf";s:9:"200italic";s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/fpTVHK8qsXbIeTHTrnQH6OptKU7UIBg2hLM7eMTU8bI.ttf";i:300;s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGFP7R5lD_au4SZC6Ks_vyWs.ttf";s:9:"300italic";s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/fpTVHK8qsXbIeTHTrnQH6DUpNKoQAsDux-Todp8f29w.ttf";s:7:"regular";s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/ODelI1aHBYDBqgeIAH2zlNRl0pGnog23EMYRrBmUzJQ.ttf";s:6:"italic";s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/M2Jd71oPJhLKp0zdtTvoMwRX4TIfMQQEXLu74GftruE.ttf";i:600;s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGOiMeWyi5E_-XkTgB5psiDg.ttf";s:9:"600italic";s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/fpTVHK8qsXbIeTHTrnQH6Pp6lGoTTgjlW0sC4r900Co.ttf";i:700;s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGPgXsetDviZcdR5OzC1KPcw.ttf";s:9:"700italic";s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/fpTVHK8qsXbIeTHTrnQH6LVT4locI09aamSzFGQlDMY.ttf";i:900;s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/toadOcfmlt9b38dHJxOBGBA_awHl7mXRjE_LQVochcU.ttf";s:9:"900italic";s:92:"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v11/fpTVHK8qsXbIeTHTrnQH6A0NcF6HPGWR298uWIdxWv0.ttf";}}}';
        return unserialize($encoded);
    }
```

Please let me know how can I add more fonts in this dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use child theme and css?
Choose your font in https://fonts.google.com-->select the font and copy the code to embed the fonts (in bottom right Family Selected), similiar to this

Now, paste this in your header.php file in child theme and then you create a class in css file, for example: .custom-font {font-family: 'Noto Serif JP', sans-serif;}-you can add a some parameters-.
Well, now add the class in your html tag : Well done!